# Auto execute method with click event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

In C#, i want to execute some method, when click event is triggered.

Not only single button click but, whole click event did this automatically.

For example, i have 3 buttons, and when i click these buttons, just execute one method.

In short, every buttons event executes the same method, when these buttons are triggered.

button1 event is triggered -> execute method0

button2 event is triggered -> execute method0

button3 event is triggered -> execute method0

Please help me. I have tons of buttons that has to execute the same method.

Comment: then make 1 method and link them all to it

Comment: or call `method0();` each `buttonX_click()`

Answer (score 7):

Just create a single method that you want to execute, then set your buttons' Click event to that:

```
void Method(object sender, EventArgs e){
// Do something
}
```

Then you can set the click event:

```
button1.Click += Method;
button2.Click += Method;
button3.Click += Method;
buttonN.Click += Method;
```

Hope it helps!